# Как с помощью ansible забрать дамп mysql базы с удалённого сервера и развернуть его локально?

Tags: ansible

Сейчас синхронизирую базы посредством git, т.е., делаю вручную дамп на удалённом хосте, коммичу, на локальном делаю пулл и разворачиваю опять же вручную. Можно ли сделать всё это с помощью ansible-playbook?

P.S. Пока сделал так:

```
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    remote_host: '...'
    dump_name: '{{ ansible_date_time.date }}_{{ ansible_date_time.epoch }}_ansible_dump.sql'
    remote_dump_path: '.../{{ dump_name }}'
    local_dump_path: '/var/www/var/database/{{ dump_name }}'
    local_db_config: 'login_user=root login_password=password encoding=utf8'
    local_db_name: '...'
    remote_db_name: '...'
    remote_db_config: '-u... -p... {{ remote_db_name }}'

  tasks:
    - name: Install/update packages
      apt: name={{ item }} state=latest
      with_items:
        - python-dev
        - libmysqlclient-dev
        - python-pip
      become: yes

    - name: Install the Python MySQLB module
      pip: name=MySQL-python
      become: yes

    - name: Create remote db dump
      command: ssh {{ remote_host }} 'mysqldump {{ remote_db_config }} > {{ remote_dump_path }}'

    - name: Compress dump
      command: ssh {{ remote_host }} 'gzip {{ remote_dump_path }}'

    - name: Get remote dump
      command: scp {{ remote_host }}:'{{ remote_dump_path }}.gz' '{{ local_dump_path }}.gz'

    - name: Remove remote dump
      command: ssh {{ remote_host }} 'rm {{ remote_dump_path }}.gz'

    - name: Unpack remote dump
      command: gzip -d '{{ local_dump_path }}.gz'

    - name: Backup local db
      mysql_db: state=dump name={{ local_db_name }} target='{{ local_dump_path }}_bak.sql' {{ local_db_config }}

    - name: Restore dump
      mysql_db: state=import name={{ local_db_name }} target={{ local_dump_path }} {{ local_db_config }}
```

Comment: Штатная репликация MySQL по каким-то причинам не подходит?

Comment: @cheops Нет рутового доступа на удалённом сервере. Вообще, можно синхронизировать разными способами. Да и вопрос был про ansible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ определенно утвердительный.

Разбить на 3 группы:

1. `vars` вынести в отдельный файл. Положить либо в `group_vars`,
       либо подключать. Править конфиги в плейбуках не правильно.
2. Сделать `inventory file`.
3. Сами задачи... Можно сделать одну роль `(DB Backup)`.

*По самим задачам:*

- Полностью отказаться от использования `command`. Это вообще зло, если
  есть специальные модули. `command` всегда показывается как
  "измененный", даже если ничего не было.
- Переписать все на модули для работы с `Mysql`, архивами и т.д. Для
  всего уже есть готовые `Core` модули (или аддоны) от `Ansible`.

Comment: @Sviderskiy Dmitriy Я правил ответ, но не давал его. Ответ дал user205771. Ему перенаправьте свои благодарности. Желательно, чтобы если ответ Вам помог, эти благодарности выражались  в голосовании за его ответ. А именно... слева около ответа есть стрелочки вверх (ответ полезен) и вниз. Выберите ту, которая кажется Вам соответствует ответу. Также под стрелочками есть галочка, выбрав которую, Вы подтвердите, что ответ верный и является принятым Вами.

Comment: @user205771 спасибо за рекомендации, позже, конечно, всё переделаю. Пока прототип )  > переписать всё на модули А какой есть модуль для command: ssh {{ remote_host }} 'mysqldump {{ remote_db_config }} > {{ remote_dump_path }}' например? (Если учесть, что на удалённом сервере нет не то что python_mysql, а вообще python?

Comment: В целом Ansible подразумевает то, что ты уже на удаленном хосте. Поэтому нет никакого смысла делать еще раз ssh. В твоем случае ты sshишься на localhost (через ansible), а потом еще раз sshшишься на localhost. Можно использовать command, если ничего нельзя сделать с remote host, но точно не еще раз ssh :)

Comment: @SviderskiyDmitriy на удаленном хосте нет python? Если это юниксовый хост, то почти наверняка там должен быть python. Если виндовый, придётся поставить. В любом случае python необходим для работы ansible как на локальном хосте (управляющем), так и на удалённом.

Comment: @user205771 добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Очень рад видеть специалиста по ansible, нас тут пока что совсем немного. )

Comment: @user205771 я на днях открыл для себя delegate_to, так что, часть проблем с выполнением команд на удалённом хосте решена. В качестве remote_host у меня не localhost, а именно remote host, так что, повторного подключения по ssh здесь, конечно же, нет.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, удалённый хост не мой, рутовых прав нема у меня там ) Так что, поставить что-то - проблема.