# Копирование файлов посредством ansible

Tags: ansible

Что-то не смог понять из примеров в документации - как же скопировать файл с удалённого сервера на локальный и наоборот? Вот есть модули copy и fetch, например. Вот я пишу в плейбуке:

```
- name: Copy file from remote host to local machine
  fetch: src=/tmp/somefile dest=/tmp/fetched(взято из доки)
```

Как указать ansible, с какого хоста я хочу скопировать файл? Ну и соответственно, при копировании на удалённый хост, где указывать этот удалённый хост?

P.S. Немного разобрался:
Чтобы скопировать файл с удалённого хоста на локальный:

```
- hosts: localhost

  vars_files:
    - config.yml

  tasks:
    - include: ../share/dev.yml

    - name: Get file from remote
      fetch: src="{{ remote_sources_path }}/test.txt" dest="backup"
      delegate_to: '{{ remote_host }}'
      tags: fetch
```

Файл test.txt будет лежать в каталоге ./backup/localhost/{{ remote_sources_path }}

Скопировать с локального на удалённый:

```
- name: Send file to remote
  copy: src="{{ local_sources_path }}/to_remote_test.txt" dest={{ remote_sources_path }}
  delegate_to: '{{ remote_host }}'
  tags: fetch
```

Подозреваю, что, если указать в начале - hosts: {{ remote_host }} вместо localhost, то delegate_to использовать не нужно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну зачем же так сложно? ))

Все эти задачи решаются и без мороки с [Delegation и Local Actions](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html), вам же самим потом сложнее будет разбираться в собственных плейбуках или читать чужие, написанные по-простому.

Смотрите.

В каждом плейбуке вы указываете на каких хостах запускать задачи - пишете `hosts: '{{ target }}'` (если хотите из командной строки управлять списком через  --extra-vars "target=10.0.100.123") или `hosts: dbservers` (если фиксировать плейбук на группу хостов):

```
---
# This playbook for quick tests.

- name: quick tests
  hosts: '{{ target }}'
  become: true
  become_user: root
  roles:
    - role1
    - role2
  tasks:
  - name: install mc
    yum: name=mc state=latest
  - name: install wget
    yum: name=wget state=latest
```

Эти хосты - "удалённый" сервер, ну а "локальный" - это само собой хост, на котором находится ваш плейбук.

Теперь:

- Для копирования файла с локального сервера на удалённый -- используете [модуль copy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html#copy)
- Для копирования файла с удалённого сервера на локальный -- используете [модуль fetch](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/fetch_module.html)

И в copy и в fetch src - это откуда брать файл, а dest - это куда положить файл. Для copy src=local а dest=remote, для fetch -- наоборот src=remote, а dest=local.

Вот и всё. Вам кстати именно об этом говорили [в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504727/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-ansible-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF-mysql-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C#comment606962_504953) к вашему последнему вопросу: "В целом Ansible подразумевает то, что ты уже на удаленном хосте", не надо нарезать лишние петли вокруг локалхоста.

PS Если нужно [копировать с произвольного хоста на произвольный хост](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505146/how-to-copy-files-between-two-nodes-using-ansible) - то смотрите в сторону [модуля syncronyze](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html) на основе rsync. Но вообще в 90% случаев вам понадобится копирование с локального хоста на удалённый и будете использовать copy или template.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже с этим разобрался ) Но вопрос, думаю, снимать не стоит, мало ли, пригодится новичкам... Тем более, что в конце я написал "Подозреваю, что, если указать в начале - hosts: {{ remote_host }} вместо localhost, то delegate_to использовать не нужно."